# Powershell - Set-ADUser after Gridview

Tags: powershell, gridview

I've very new to PowerShell and just starting learn. I'm very appreciative for any help.

Here is what I'm after:  I would like to set several OUs to search for AD users who have the Dial-In tab selected as True or Null (Control access through NPS Network Policy) and display the results in gridview.  the first part of my script is working, at least displaying the correct users in gridview. Once user(s) are selected in gridview pass those user to have their setting changed to False (deny access).

The error I have is: Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

```
$OUs = 'OU=Test,DC=Test,DC=net'


$users = $OUs | Foreach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(msNPAllowDialin -eq $True) -or (msNPAllowDialin -notlike "*")} -SearchBase $_ -Properties msNPAllowDialin,description,SamAccountName | 
    Select-Object Name,@{Name="BT UserID";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}},Description | Sort-Object name | 
    Out-GridView -Title "Select One or More Users to Change Setting" -PassThru
}


$user = $users | foreach { 

    Set-ADUser $user -replace @{msnpallowdialin=$False}
    Write-Host "$($_.name) Dial-In Setting Changed" -ForegroundColor cyan

}
```

Comment: `Set-ADUser $user ...` -> `Set-ADUser $_ ...`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I did try that too and this error

Set-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser". The adapter cannot set the value of 
property "Name".

Comment: Add property `SamAccountName` to the Select-Object statement and use that as `-Identity` for `Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName`

Comment: @Theo - Thank you!  As I'm still learning I thought I had it even though I changed the name with my expression.  Looks like I was wrong, much appreciated with the help!

Comment: You're welcome!